# How to terminate this program on while loop and why error message prints out before user input?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am doing an assignment and I am having two problems. Thank you for any help you can offer!

My first problem is terminating the program with user entry. I've gotten the program to loop upon incorrect data, but I am not sure where to put a while loop so that "Done" will terminate the program anywhere.

My second problem is that I can't figure out why the program skips input for annual salary and prints the error message:

Example of output:

> Last name:  [Jean]
>
> First name: [Martha]
>
> Annual salary: [skips]
>
> Error: Please enter a number
>
> Annual Salary: [allows input]

Here is the part of my code that I'm working on:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BaseSalary
{  

  public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    String tempBaseSalary=null;
    String salespersonName=null;
    Double baseSalary=0.0;
    String end = "Done";

//tried putting while(salespersonName.equals(end))  here allow user to terminate

      salespersonName = getSalespersonName();


//tried while(!tempBaseSalary.equals(end)) in same manner

      tempBaseSalary = getBaseSalary();       //get baseSalary

      while(!isNumeric(tempBaseSalary))       // loop until tempBaseSalary is a number
      {

        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number");       //Why is printing out before user input??
        tempBaseSalary=getBaseSalary();
      }   

      baseSalary=Double.parseDouble(tempBaseSalary);  //convert for future calculations
      System.out.println("Saleserson name:" + salespersonName);   
      System.out.println("Base Salary:" + baseSalary);
  }

  public static String getSalespersonName()           //method gets SalespersonName
  {

    String lastName, firstName;

    System.out.println("Last name:");
    lastName=keyboard.next();

    System.out.println("First name:");
    firstName=keyboard.next();

    return (firstName + " " + lastName);

  }


  public static String getBaseSalary()           // method gets baseSalary
  {
    String salary=null;

    System.out.println("annual salary:");  
    salary=keyboard.nextLine();
    return salary;

  }

  public static boolean isNumeric(String number)  //method tests if BaseSalary is a #
  {

    if(number.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

By the way I am currently using Dr. Java. Again, thank you for any help in advance! Let me know if you need anything other information or clarification.

Comment: can you please ask 1 question per question?

Comment: Sorry! Should I edit this and make a new question for the second question?

Comment: Instead of using a while loop to check for anything input being equal to `end`, why not put a `while (true) {` around the whole thing, and after every input, use an `if` statement to check if the user entered `"Done"` and if they did, break from the loop.

Comment: Also, I think you should use `keyboard.nextLine();` instead of `keyboard.next();` in the `getSalespersonName()` method.

Comment: @jon Do you mean put the while(true) {} around everything in the main method or in the getSalespersonName and getBaseSalary Methods?

Comment: @GessaGessa I was talking about in the main method. But it really depends what you want to do. I was thinking you wanted to loop through the program over and over, creating new salespeople until the user enters "Done". But if you only want one salesperson and are just looking for a way to exit the program from anywhere if the user enters "Done", after every `keyboard.next()` or `keyboard.nextLine()`, do `if (theVariableYouPutTheInputInto.equals(end)) { System.exit(0); }`

Comment: @jon You were right the first time. However, when I do the `while(true)` and put `if(condition) break;` `else continue;` under the input, when I compile the program `tempBaseSalary = getBaseSalary()` becomes unreachable code.

Comment: Take out the `continue`. That makes it so the loop skips everything after the `continue` and starts at the top again, effectively making it so `getBaseSalary()` is unreachable because you will *always* be doing the `break` or the `continue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `System.exit(0);` to finish the app
you can do i in a while loop like that

```
int i , integer1
while(i<10){
    codes... + an integer1++
}
if (integer1>10){
    System.exit(0);
}
else{
//don't do anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make two arrays of strings (or an array of your own objects, or a two-dimensional array of strings); one array holds prompts, the other is filled with responses.  Loop through the array, outputting the prompt, getting the input.  If the input is "done", terminate the loop, otherwise put it in the array at the same position in the input array as the prompt had in the prompt array.

Or you can have your own class that will hold a prompt and a response to the prompt, and have an array of those.

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to use a 2-d array for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `next()` instead of `nextLine()` in `getBaseSalary()`. Should solve your second problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `salary = keyboard.next()` in your `getBaseSalary()` method to solve your second problem.

```
public static String getBaseSalary() // method gets baseSalary
    {
        String salary = null;

        System.out.println("annual salary:");
        salary = keyboard.next();
        return salary;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question: 
When you enter second name , the buffer still has `\n` in it from the `enter` you hit after entering last name from console. So your annual salary by default read the rest of the line which would be `\n` and hence it fails.
suggestion: use .nextLine() in both first name and second name like ,

```
System.out.println("Last name:");
lastName=keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("First name:");
firstName=keyboard.nextLine();
```

regarding the first question, first you need to identify which entry you expect to be `done` , ie firstName or lastName. After you find that out, you can compare the entry to your variable `end` . Suppose you want to terminate when input for `firstName` is `done`, then you will do

```
if(end.equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
  System.exit(0);
```

You would perform this comparision and exit the system after you receive the input from the user for that variable. In this case, this would be done after you receive user entry for `firstName` .